# error on GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, import, grid

```
import java.awt.Container; //Container or *
import javax.swing.*; //JFrame, JLabel, *, or etc...

public class NumerologyEC extends JFrame
{
    private static final int Width = 400;
    private static final int Height = 300;

    private JLabel word1;

   public  NumerologyEC()
   {
       setTitle ("Numerology Extra Credit");
       word1 = new JLabel ("Enter a word: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

       Container pane = getContentPane();
       pane.setLayout (new GridLayout (1, 2));

       pane.add(word1);

       setSize(Width, Height);
       setVisible (true);
       setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
    NumerologyEC rectObject = new NumerologyEC();
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error on "new GridLayout." im following the book for my class and it doesnt explain if i need to import something or declare it to make it work. any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use an IDE such as Eclipse, NetBeans, or IntelliJ IDEA, it can assist you in adding the necessary imports (in IDEA one would type Alt-Enter, in Eclipse, Shift-Ctrl-O).

Answer (score 1):

You do need to also import `GridLayout`. Add this import

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
```

Or you could change your import to the following to import everything in the package

```
import java.awt.*;
```

Or explicitly write

```
new java.awt.GridLayout (1, 2)
```